# Setting a current node pointer to either a right or left node in a binary tree

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-search-tree

I have looked through quite extensively (and hopefully haven't missed it) but I cannot seem to find any help in my current predicament. So here is the problem:

I am attempting to change my current node in a binary tree to either the right or left child depending on what the user wants to do, I have several other functions in the program I.E. (move up, move down-right, move down-left) and then you can cout the current item. The issue is that I can change the item to the right child but not the left one, it is as if the left child does not exist... Here is the code snippet of what I am attempting to do:

```
`else if (choice == 3)
        {
            if (Ptr->left != NULL)
            {
                system("CLS");
                current = Ptr->left;
                std::cout << "Moved to the left item..." << std::endl;
                system("PAUSE");
            }

            else
            {
                system("CLS");
                std::cout << "Cannot move left any further..." << std::endl;
                system("PAUSE");
            }
        }`
```

The same technique is applied to the right-side as well. I am quite new to trees and perhaps an "array" style tree would be better than my current dynamic tree, I am using a recursive function that is dynamically re-sized as needed by the user. Hopefully I included all the relevant information. If I need to put anything else in I would happily do so to get some help! Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might even solve your own problem in the meantime.

Comment: I decided to re-create the entire tree as an array. Which, as to right now of writing this seems to have solved most of my issues. That MCVE definitely helped me to reach this though! Thanks!